# What happens when the last added block in a blockchain is corrupted?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-fork, block-validity

What happens when the last added block in a blockchain is corrupted? Is it still possible for the block to be accepted by a majority of the miners?

Answer (score 3):

By definition a node's idea of the blockchain is among all valid versions of history the one with the most total proof of work.

Because chains are required to be valid, it is not possible to have a block in there that violates consensus rules. It doesn't matter what miners do; full nodes will still ignore the block entirely, as if it was never created.

Answer (score 1):

Every full node unilaterally checks each block for validity. When a block does not adhere to the consensus rules, a full node will not accept it as valid, will not consider included transactions as confirmed, and will not forward it to other nodes.

A similar incident happened for example in July when Antminer accidentally claimed a higher block reward than permitted in block 584,802.

You can read about that a bit more for example here:
https://twitter.com/bitmexresearch/status/1148989508588883970